# Http 500 error via .htaccess & godaddy

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, localhost, http-status-code-500

I'm getting http 500 error .. I think it has to do with .htaccess and server hosting in godaddy.

- When im working through localhost via xampp its working well but when I bring the files to godaddy hosting its not

Does anyone know what is the problem here? TIA

1.
[image]

2.

[image]

Comment: Learn http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

Comment: When im working through localhost via xampp its working well but when I bring the files to godaddy hosting its not @madankundu

Comment: I'm surprised it's working at all even on xampp - it looks like 2 different .htaccess file that have been clobbered together; 2x `RewriteEngine On` and conflicting `-f -d` *"router"* redirects...

Comment: There are two things that are 1. index.php is not listed at all 2. you can freely produce Subdommain ... like mac.localhost or mac.domain.com

Comment: @cd001i remove  the -f -d part but its not working...

Comment: the `!-f` means not a file `!-d` means not a directory, you don't want to remove them but you've got two redirects attempting to do the same thing - you probably want to either delete everything above `# Turn mod_rewrite on` or everything below - as I said, it looks like 2 .htaccess files kludged together.